# How to calculate the speed of falling ball in sprite kit

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

I'm trying to get a bouncing ball effect which i'm not really having a problem with.
what i'm trying to figure out is how can i calculate the speed of the ball.

I know this is how its done in Box2d
    
    `b2Vec2 velocity = b->GetLinearVelocity();

    float32 speed = velocity.Length();`

how are these lines converted to sprite kit?
Thanks

Edit:
i'm trying this any idea if this is correct for speed

```
static inline CGFloat CGPointLength(const CGVector a) {
    return sqrtf(a.dx * a.dx + a.dy * a.dy);
}

  CGVector velocity=circle.physicsBody.velocity;
  float speed=CGPointLength(velocity);
```

Answer (score 3):

The `SKNode`'s `physicsBody` has a `CGVector` property for `velocity` that you would use to calculate the speed.